# Is there a way in which I can get the equivalent list of vectors per paragraph in doc2vec?

Tags: python, doc2vec

Is there a way to see the vectors I got per paragraphs and not per each word in the vocabulary with doc2vec. By using `model.wv.vectors` I get all the vectors per words. Now, I would need this in order to apply a clusterization algorithm on the embedded paragraphs which I can hopefully obtain. I am not sure though if this approach is good. This is how the paragraphs look:

`[TaggedDocument(words=['this', 'is', 'the', 'effect', 'of', 'those', 'states', 'that', 'went', 'into', 'lockdown', 'much', 'later', 'they', 'are', 'just', 'starting', 'to', 'see', 'the', 'large', 'increase', 'now', 'they', 'have', 'to', 'ride', 'it', 'out', 'and', 'hope', 'for', 'the', 'best'], tags=[0])`

`TaggedDocument(words=['so', 'see', 'the', 'headline', 'is', 'died', 'not', 'revised', 'predictions', 'show', 'more', 'hopeful', 'situation', 'or', 'new', 'york', 'reaching', 'apex', 'long', 'before', 'experts', 'predicted', 'or', 'any', 'such', 'thing', 'got', 'to', 'keep', 'the', 'panic', 'train', 'rolling', 'see'], tags=[1])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`model.docvecs.vectors` will contain all the trained-up document vectors.

Comment: also is there a way to see the corresponding paragraph to each vector? It looks like there are more paragraphs than doc vectors. Why is that?

Comment: There will be one doc-vector, named by `tag`, learned in the model for every unique `tag` you've provided, in the training data. The trained model does not store the original texts – in many cases that'd be an unmanageable amount of data. Instead, you should rely on your original data source, & your choice of tag-to-text mapping, to retrieve full texts from there, if needed. (The model just enables looking up vectors by `tag`, or inferring new vectors for new texts, or giving ranked lists of similar tags.)

Comment: If you fed it more texts than the model wound up with as unique tags/doc-vectors, maybe some tags repeated? (What count of doc-vectors did you expect to get, and what count did you actually get? Are you sure your training texts are `TaggedDocuments` just like the examples you show, with a single `tag` each that's a unique escalating integer?)